# Ubuntu SDK and shared.h

Tags: application-development, compiling, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

I'm trying to make some experiments with the Ubuntu SDK and I found a problem with the sample files.
If I create a new app, I can compile and run it without problems. If I try to select one of the examples, such as Qt Quick Demo - Clocks, and then I choose to copy it in my working directory, when I try to 'Run' it I obtain the following error:

```
/home/cialu/Development/UbuntuSDKProjects/clocks/main.cpp:40: error: $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/quick/shared/shared.h: No such file or directory
#include "$$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/quick/shared/shared.h"
```

I have tried to find SHARED.H to give a different path on the include, but not found it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, nobody found that?

```
locate shared.h
```

Gives among others:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/quick/shared/shared.h
```